# What is the DK function when generating an AES key for Kerberos 5?

Tags: aes, kerberos

I'm trying to understand [RFC3962](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3962). So far I understood everything, except for the [last](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3962#section-4) part: generating the derived key from the PBKDF2 output.

> To generate an encryption key from a pass phrase and salt string, we
> use the PBKDF2 function from PKCS #5 v2.0 ([PKCS5]), with parameters
> indicated below, to generate an intermediate key (of the same length
> as the desired final key), which is then passed into the DK function
> with the 8-octet ASCII string "kerberos" as is done for des3-cbc-
> hmac-sha1-kd in [KCRYPTO].  (In [KCRYPTO] terms, the PBKDF2 function
> produces a "random octet string", hence the application of the
> random-to-key function even though it's effectively a simple identity
> operation.)  The resulting key is the user's long-term key for use
> with the encryption algorithm in question.

```
tkey = random2key(PBKDF2(passphrase, salt, iter_count, keylength))
key = DK(tkey, "kerberos")
```

I understood that the random2key part means nothing in this context, but I don't understand to which function is referenced with `DK`.

Comment: Wait what? Somebody added 'kerberos 5' to the title. What is Kerberos 5?

Comment: Kerberos, version 5. (Take a closer look at the title of RFC3962.)

Comment: DK() is the key derivation procedure outlined in [RFC3961](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3961#section-5.1)

Comment: @squeamishossifrage still that makes no sense. For example, DK(Key, Constant) = random-to-key(DR(Key, Constant)) what is the random-to-key? And  k-truncate(E(Key, Constant,
                                       initial-cipher-state)), E is not defined anywhere, and I cant understand what the initial-cipher-state is (apart from all bits being zero)

Comment: Yes it does. Keep reading. [Section 5 of RFC3962](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3962#section-5) describes how the initial cipher state is obtained, and as [section 6](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3962#section-6) says, *random-to-key()* is the identity function (i.e., the output is the same as the input). *E()* is the encryption function (AES in CBC-CTS mode).